# Jenkins - Automating updating Dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, jenkins, msbuild, continuous-integration

I have Jenkins pulling from SVN on occasion. If there's a commit on a project it will rebuild the project with a new version number. I'd like to find a way to update the references to this project in the projects that depend on it. I've had no such luck finding anything yet.

So for example I have Project A, B, and C. A is a data layer and B,C are dependent on it. When the assembly info/version of A is updated I need B and C to reference this new Version.

Does anyone have an experience doing something like this?

Comment: sure, that seems reasonable. what part are you having trouble with? is there a command you would run in project B on your laptop to update the referenced version of project A? how about making a jenkins job that does that that you could kick off when project A builds?

Comment: so far there is nothing in place to update a reference. It's done manually by going into the project. The last part there is really the question I have. I want to add it as an automated post-build step when project A is built but I'm not sure how to go about doing that in the best way.

Answer (score 0):

In our Jenkins CI we use a combination of Artifactory and Ivy.  Whenever we build a CI build we set the ivy dependency to 'latest.integration'. This automatically chooses the latest CI build of that dependency.

http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/bestpractices.html

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a look!